# Spring MVC IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

I have a form in a modal window. This modal window can appear on any page from my website. From this form I want to send the information to my controller, but I get an exception. Let's me present my code:

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update-profile.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String modalUpdateProfile(
    @ModelAttribute("profile") Profile profil, BindingResult result, 
    Errors errors, RedirectAttributes ra
) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if (!result.hasErrors()) {
        profileService.modifyAndUpdate(profil, auth.getName());
        return "redirect:/profilul-meu.html";
    }
    return "my-profile";
}
```

And this is my form:

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="profile" class="form-horizontal"
    action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/update-profile.html">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nume">First Name: </label>
            <form:input id="nume" type="text" class="form-control"
                path="first_name" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="prenume">Second Name: </label>
            <form:input id="prenume" type="text" class="form-control"
                path="second_name" />
        </div>
</form:form>
```

This is my dipsatcher-servlet.xml:

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.gab.gsn.controller" />

<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/template-def/general.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
</bean>
```

So, when I want visit an page of my application I get this message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'profile' available as request attribute
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:117)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.template_002ddef.layout_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(layout_jsp.java:2343)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.template_002ddef.layout_jsp._jspService(layout_jsp.java:416)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.forward(ServletRequest.java:265)
    org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.doForward(ServletRequest.java:228)
    org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractClientRequest.dispatch(AbstractClientRequest.java:57)
    org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
```

Comment: where is your form GET handler?

Answer (score 0):

Need to add model attribute in controller like ..modalUpdateProfile(...,Model model) and add profile object to model.